# Handling Conditional Property Serialization in C# Request Classes

Tags: c#, .net

Firstly, let's consider a class in our project. This class serves as a request class.

```
public class InsertStudentRequest : IRequest<InsertStudentResponse>
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StdNo { get; set; }
    public Transcript Transcript { get; set; }
}

public class InsertBulkStudentRequest : IRequest<InsertBulkStudentResponse>
{
    public List<InsertStudentRequest> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

As seen here, the Id property in InsertStudentRequest is ignored using JsonIgnore, preventing any value assignment when Swagger is run. The same applies to bulk requests using InsertBulkStudentRequest, where Id cannot be provided in both individual and bulk insert operations.

Now, if I want to avoid entering Transcript information for students when performing bulk requests, how can I ignore the Transcript objects? I can't use JsonIgnore this time, as it would prevent Transcript entry even in individual student entries. So, I need a solution.

Comment: Can you explain why Id and Transcript have to be part of the request, if you dont need it?

Comment: This is merely an illustrative example. For instance, I could populate them in code, or I might not require transcripts when inserting a large number of students. Does this have any significance? @MichaelSchönbauer

I have just wonder how to ignore Transcript while inserting bulk students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, if I want to avoid entering Transcript information for students when performing bulk requests, how can I ignore the Transcript objects?

Just create a special subset of DTOs/models to handle different scenarios and then setup mapping between them and you internal handling pipeline. This would be by far easiest option in most cases, then conditional serialization/binding.

I.e. the bulk insert endpoint would accept something like:

```
public class InsertBulkStudentDTO
{
    public List<BulkStudentInsertInfo> Requests { get; set; }
}

public class BulkStudentInsertInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StdNo { get; set; }
}
```

You can introduce some base classes/common interfaces to share/enforce common properties and use one of the many mappers which exist for C# (like Mapster, AutoMapper, etc.) to simplify mapping setup.